# How do I code a GUI-"History" of a player's scores?

Tags: c#, image, user-interface, formatting, scrollbar

So, I'm coding a "game history" that the user enters and that information entered is turned into an image-file that is displayed.  It's hard to explain -- just take a look at the mock-sketch I created:

[image]

Essentially, what I'm trying to do is have the user click the "Add New" button and the GUI pops up. Inside of the GUI, the user will have a few options of which ICON they used, WIN/LOSS, what type of game it was, and a couple of stats.  I'd like everything the user inputs to create a new History Record (an image) with the ICON, WIN, Type, stat1, stat2, stat3 in the pre-defined locations that I've labeled... The problem I'm running into is simply "How do I make my code create a new image based on the information the user has inputted. -- and have a working scrollbar on the side."

I was thinking something along the lines of having a picture-gallery type of a setup that could accommodate the History Records... but I just don't know how to use code to create the image itself from data the user enters.

*Note: I know I can use the text-to-image features from .NET, but the problem is that I have an ICON (image) on the side as well, which makes it complicated.  I'm a little lost on how to put everything together.  Any would would be MUCH appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, don't use script fonts for UI.

Comment: Many GUI widget libraries let you subclass e.g. the `Button` class and extend the label to a horizontal box container that includes a picture on one side and text on another or do whatever else you want to the labels.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a VB guy, so:

```
Dim tFont As Font = New Font("font name", ...)
Dim tImage As Bitmap = New Bitmap (150, 50)
Using tGraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(tImage)
  tGraphics.DrawImage(...)  ' Draw your image/icon at the appropriate place
  tGraphics.DrawString(...) ' Draw your text in the appropriate places
End Using
```